# Mandrill Templates With Handlebars - How To Format Date

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill, date-formatting, email-templates

Mandrill has a great feature that allows one to use Handlebars in templates to customize email content. See docs [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content).

One of the helpers that Madnrill supports is `date` that can be used like `{{#date}}`. The default date format is `d/m/Y`. My question is how can I specify a different date format (e.g. `yyyy`)?

I need to display something like `2015 Name`. I tried:

- `{{#date yyyy}} Name` - displays `05/31/15` (default format and seems to erase any HTML after it).
- `{{#date 'yyyy'}} Name` - displays `{{#date 'yyyy'}} Name` (can't be parsed).
- `{{#date yyyy}}{{/date}} Name` - displays `05/31/15 Name` (default format).
- `{{#date 'yyyy'}}{{/date}} Name` - displays `{{#date 'yyyy'}}{{/date}} Name` (can't be parsed).

Appreciate you help ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was 2-fold:

- You should use `{{date}}` instead of `{{#date}}`
- You should use double quotes for formatting

The correct syntax would be `{{date "Y"}}`.

Mandrill also updated their [docs](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content) that now provide more details on handlebars syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume this may follow the original Merge Tag formatting. Have you tried this?

http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheatsheet

Use *|DATE:FORMAT|* to show the current date in a given format. For example, *|DATE:d/m/y|* where d is replaced by the day, m by the month, and y by the year. View a full reference of date options on the [PHP website](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). This format isn't available for automation workflows.